# What happened to the adjectival forms of Belize and Singapore in their currencies?

Tags: adjectives, money

It's been researched that every country has their adjectival form (exception is a [demonym](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demonym), which denotes nouns), such as the adjectival form of Mexico is Mexican, the adjectival form of Russia is Russian, and their currencies are "Mexican peso" and "Russian ruble", respectively.

In currencies, mostly I have found adjectival forms of the countries e.g. Mexican peso and Russian ruble. But what happened to the adjectival forms of Belize, Singapore, Lesotho and Turkmenistan, as their currencies are:

- **[Belize dollar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belize_dollar)** (rather than Belizean dollar)
- **[Singapore dollar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_dollar)** (rather than Singaporean dollar)
- **[Lesotho loti](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesotho_loti)** (rather than Basotho loti)

> It's been noted that the word "Basotho" is both demonym as well as the adjectival form of Lesotho. And "Basotho" as a demonym is plural per se; its singular form is "Mosotho".

- **[Turkmenistan manat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkmenistani_manat)** (rather than Turkmenistani manat)

Out of 190+ countries, these countries are the exceptions which have no any adjectival forms in their currencies.

The Google Search Engine supports what I thought of those adjectival forms. See that when you type "Singaporean dollar" on Google, then it pops up that exact option, but when you search it, it doesn't show any exact result, rather it says Singapore Dollar. I wish I could know its reason.

Comment: It's an interesting question about national adjectives but they are not demonyms. A demonym (/ˈdɛmənɪm/; from Greek δῆμος, dẽmos, "people, tribe" and όνομα, ónoma, "name") is a word that identifies residents or natives of a particular place, which is derived from the name of that particular place. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym). Sometimes the adjective and the demonym are the same (e.g. *Mexican*) but they aren't always.

Comment: For that matter, we say "U.S. dollar", not "American dollar".

Comment: I suspect it is a question of quick pronounciation.  *Singapore* is shorter and easier to pronounce  than *Singaporean* while,  Mexican and Russian,  for instance, are not much different from Mexico and Russia. Currency traders use these terms in buying and selling currencies for hundreds/thousands transactions carried out every day, especially in the past (before pervasive technology was introduced in finance) so the shorter the term, the quicker and the better. Btw the term that currency traders use for the Singapore Dollar is “Sing Dollar”.

Comment: What is the adjectival form of USA?

Comment: @malvolio There is no adjective from the *USA* *per se*. *America* is used as an unambiguous synonym and *its* adjective is *American*. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States) discussed the terminology. It does not give the adjective but it gives the demonym and when a demonym is adjectival in form we can assume it is the adjective. The situation is very different from the UK where the adjective *British* from *Britain* is used but is both ambiguous and controversial.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but what it is about is not specific to currencies. There seems to be a general reluctance to use adjectives such as *Singaporean*: compare, for example, 'Singapore Airlines' with 'Austrian Airlines'. The same reluctance exists with respect to the adjectives formed out of the names of the states within the U.S.: one does not hear the adjective *Californian* very often, for example.

Comment: @jsw29 I’m not sure I buy that. _Singaporean_ is the obvious and first choice for me in many contexts. A restaurant that serves Singaporean (!) food is a Singaporean restaurant, for example, not a *Singapore restaurant. Airlines are not really anything to by – there’s too much random variation. Consider China Airlines and Japan Airlines vs Turkish Airlines and Thai Airways, though all four adjectives are very frequent.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, true, the name of the airline proves very little. A casual Internet search will, however, still lead to quite a few cases, that do not involve currencies, of *Singapore* or *California* being used where *Singaporean/Californian* could have seen used; *Austria* or *Romania* are never so used.

Comment: Your Question would be wholly reasonable, were it not that as you said, Lesotho loti (rather than Mosotho loti (Mosotho is singular, while Basotho is plural).

Please first translate all of that into English…

Comment: @Robbie, thanks a bunch! I have now clarified it as you suggested.

Answer (score 5):

There is no strict rule based on grammar that you can give as there is no fixed rule for how to form an adjective from a country. Who would guess that *French* is the adjective from *France*? So if the country and its currency are referred to often people will know the adjective.

If the adjective is easy to guess it will help. For example many countries end in an *a* and you just add an *n* such as *Latvia* > *Latvian*. This is why we do not use *Mosotho*. (Note that *Argentinean* appears to be an exception but it probably comes from *The Argentine* not from Argentina.)

If the adjective is long (*Singaporean*) or sounds strange in English (*Belizean*) it will also be a deterrent.

So overall there are several factors which affect how likely we are to use the adjective.

There is one well known country that does not have an adjective of its own. This is the UK. There is a historical reason for this. Before [1801](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acts_of_Union_1800), *Britain* and the *UK* were virtually the same but in 1801 Ireland was added to the UK. As Ireland was only gradually accepted into the union no one ever invented the adjective for the UK. For example they had their own currency until [1826](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_pound). This means that *British* was the logically correct adjective for the currency until then.

The reason for going on about the UK is because it shows that there may be historical reasons for using a particular word in a particular country. For example the Russian rouble is not the currency of Russia *per se* but the [currency of the Russian Federation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_ruble) and before that the USSR and the Russian Empire. In short there may be historical reasons specific to a given currency.

Comment: This answer is probably on the right track, but one may still wonder what precisely it is that makes *Belizean* 'sound strange' in English? Why does it sound more strange than, say, *Peruvian*? Some explicit account of its strangeness is needed to make it clear that its sounding strange is not due merely to its being rarely heard (which would make the explanation circular).

Comment: I totally agree, @jsw29, that we need a reference to some research if there is any, and that the argument appears circular. All I can say is that I can't think of any words that sound like *Belizean*, that is, I can't think of any rhymes, whereas I can think of a rhyme for *Peruvian*, namely [*antediluvian*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antediluvian). One could do some research to see if the existence of rhymes influences how likely the adjective is to be used. It would be complicated as there are several other factors, as already discussed, that would have to be taken into account.

Comment: @David Robinson Nitpick re "no one ever invented the adjective for the UK": the humorous coinage *UKoGBaNIan* does exist, but obviously it is not used seriously or in wide-spread fashion. See also [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/UKoGBaNIan)