# How to say non-USD currencies

Tags: measuring-units, money

How would someone say the following when spoken (i.e. a financial report):

> USD currently trading at SGD $1.36

I think both (A), (B), (C) below are valid and common (using the **bold** word before the word "dollar") but is there other way of saying it?

- (A) "U.S. dollar currently trading at one point thirty-six **Singaporean** dollars"
- (B) "U.S. dollar currently trading at one point three six **Singaporean** dollars"
- (C) "U.S. dollar currently trading at one **Singaporean** dollar [and] thirty-six cents"
- (D) Some other way. If so, how? Please provide examples
  　　i.e. "U.S. dollar currently trading at one dollar [and] thirty-six **Singaporean** cents"

Note that thing in "[ ]" are optional. You can say it with or without it.

Comment: They’re Singapore Dollars though, not Singaporean.

Comment: Related: [What happened to the adjectival forms of Belize and Singapore in their currencies?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473569/what-happened-to-the-adjectival-forms-of-belize-and-singapore-in-their-currencie?rq=1)

Comment: In spoken reports the emphasis is on **speed** and **clarity**. For example, in the business, USD and HKD are referred to as “dollars” and “honkies”. Each currency has its own local name, such as the “loonie” for CAD. However US dollars and British pounds are simply “dollars” and “pounds”.

Comment: To be clear, names like "loonie" for the Canadian dollar is a nickname. The currency would be just called "dollar" in normal speech, and "Canadian dollar" if it is not clear which dollar is meant.

Comment: We don't say a U.S. dollar: it's just: US dollar trading at x

Comment: "U.S. dollar currently trading at one dollar [and] thirty-six Singaporean cents" doesn't specify what sort of dollar the second dollar is, although you can probably guess, but it's not very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Normally the adjective form of the nationality is used:

- British pounds
- Canadian dollars
- American dollars
- Japanese Yen

Sometimes the noun form can be used instead. This is usually done when the adjective form is substantially longer than the  noun form (or otherwise hard to say). Singaporean adds two syllables to the noun form and so is a likely candidate. Hong Kong (Hongkongese) would be another.

All this applies equally to items other than currencies - Canadian landscape; British military; Singapore government; Japanese heritage.

Comment: [@DJClayworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/695/djclayworth) Thank you for the comment. Is it usually before the dollar and not before the cents?

Comment: You are welcome. You can acknowledge the answer by voting it up (click the up arrow) and accepting it (click the checkmark under the arrows)

Comment: Actually, I did not cast the down vote and right now I am just waiting for other answers before closing it. Also if you could, could you comment on if the adjective (i.e. Singaporean) or noun (i.e. Singapore) goes in front of the dollar or the cent (in other words, is the example in (D) valid clarification?).

Comment: In finance, it's US dollar. Not American dollar.

Comment: Pounds Sterling, please.